# iOS UIAppearance Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiappearance

I'm building a file management app, and I occasionally get the following error while calling a `UIImagePickerController` or a `MPMediaPickerController`:

```
*** -[_UIImageViewPretiledImageCacheKey hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x140dc0
```

I recently gave my app a custom theme using iOS 5's UIAppearance API and thats when I started getting this error. By guessing and checking, I found the problematic lines of my code that cause this error:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 16, 12, 8)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIImage *barButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"barButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(14, 12, 14, 12)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have no idea how this code triggers the above error. Can you please explain to me the source of this error and provide a solution to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Guvvy

Comment: For those unlucky enough to be seeing this crash, here's another very useful resource: http://openradar.appspot.com/11411000

Comment: do we know why this happens yet? I'm getting the same thing in iOS 6. I am custom drawing my own 20x20 images and have cap insets of 9 on all sides...

Comment: @bogardon are you getting this crash on non-retina devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more thorough testing, I have reached the conclusion that this problem is limited to retina devices. The issue turned out to be in the @2x images. They had a odd numbered resolution (eg. 59px by 60px). All I did was recreate the image and changed the resolution to 60px by 60px and I never experienced the problem again.

I was kind of surprised by the solution as I saw no correlation between the error message and the line of code, but in the end, it was the images that caused this problem.

Comment: My @2x images dont have odd numbered resolution but this crash still occurs occasionally...

Answer (score 2):

I had a [similar problem](http://openradar.appspot.com/12994960), but my crash was caused by a resizable image in a `UIImageView`.

My resizable image has edge insets of top=30px, left=20px, bottom=1px, right=10px. The image is 43x45, so its resizable area is 13x14. I'm using iOS6, so I was able to workaround the problem by specifying `UIImageResizingModeStretch` as the `resizingMode` for `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:]`.

Works:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
UIImage *resizableImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or `[_UIImageViewPretiledImageCacheKey hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb14deb0` with `NSZombieEnabled`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
UIImage *resizableImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same for the following code

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage stretchableImageNamed:@"imageName"];
self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

where `self` is `UITableViewCell` and `stretchableImageNamed:` is simply

```
+(UIImage*)stretchableImageNamed:(NSString*)name
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    CGSize sz = img.size;
    int left = (sz.width - 1.) / 2.;
    int top = (sz.height - 1.) / 2.;
    return [img resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, top, left)];
}
```

this helped:

```
self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage stretchableImageNamed:@"imageName"]];
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage stretchableImageNamed:@"imageName"]];
```